# Proper way to extend Ext.panel.Panel?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I am creating a GUI for a webpage using Ext JS 4.1.1. I have tried to create a component ('*GeneSearchComponent*' below) which I can use in a more complicated layouts. But for some reason I cannot insert an instance of '*GeneSearchComponent*' into *hpanel*. What am I missing in extending the pre-defined '*Ext.panel.Panel*' class (and in creating a "widget" of my own)?

If I remove the call to "`Ext.create('gene-search-component', ...`", everything works; if I put it back in, everything breaks. I wonder why.

(I have not included the definition of 'gene-combobox'. I am pretty convinced that it's not the root cause of my problem.)

Thanks for your time!

Tuomas

```js
Ext.define('GeneSearchComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: ['gene-search-component'],
    constructor: function(cnfg) {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.initConfig(cnfg);
    },
    config: {
        collapsible: true,
        frame: true,
        title: 'Search',
        bodyPadding: '15 15 15 15',
        width: 350,
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox', 
            align: 'left'
        },
        items: [
            Ext.widget('gene-combobox', {
                id: 'comboboxid'
            }),
            Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
                text: 'Search',
                handler: function() {
                    dosomething();
        }})]
    },
    onRender: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'FW',
    launch: function() {
        var bd = Ext.getBody();
        var div = Ext.get("search_form");

        var hpanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            id: 'horizontal-panel',
            title: "HBoxLayout Panel",
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'middle'
            },
            items: [
                Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
                    id: 'another-panel',
                    title: "VBoxLayout Panel",
                    width: 250,
                    layout: {
                        type: 'vbox',
                        align: 'left'
                    },
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        width: 250,
                        title: ' Panel One',
                        flex: 2
                    },{
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        width: 250,
                        title: ' Panel Two',
                        flex: 1
                    },{
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        width: 250,
                        title: ' Panel Three',
                        flex: 1
                }]}),
                Ext.create('gene-search-component', {
                    id: 'searchPanel',
            })],
            renderTo: div,
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Why have you defined a custom `constructor` for `GeneSearchComponent`? Also, why using `Ext.widget` and `Ext.create` when you can use `xtype`? While not certain, these could be the source of your problems.

Comment: lzhaki, if I remove the constructor, javascript engine no longer complains about "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setOwner'." However, leaving it out affects how components are rendered. As far as xtype, Ext.widget and Ext.create are concerned, I thought they are more or less equivalent to each other.

Comment: Could you give more details on what effect leaving the constructor out has? Also, it could well matter whether one uses `Ext.create` or 'lazy Instantiation' using `xtype`, but the explanation behind it is complex and I suggest you start by reading [this](http://skirtlesden.com/articles/config-objects-on-the-prototype).

Comment: Also, why do you define `config:` rather than just providing the configs as configs (ie, outside a `config:` block)?

Comment: lzhaki, if I leave the constructor out, GeneSearchComponent's width becomes almost 100% of the page, and the blue "header" with "Search" text disappears. I will read the page you linked to. As far as configs are concerned, I was mostly copycatting what I've read online here and there. Not a fully conscious choice. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have not given the `gene-search-component` the `widget` namespace when configuring its alias.

```
alias: 'widget.gene-search-component'
```

Also to echo the comments on your OP you are doing a lot of unnecessary typing creating components in the way that you are. You should make use of the xtype field rather than using Ext.Create everywhere. I've modified your code to show you how much simpler it could be.

http://jsfiddle.net/hzXx8/

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to get it work. I do appreciate the simplicity of your code. lzhaki and Jamie, thanks for taking your time with this. Hopefully some day I can pay back the favor.